# Etherchannel / Inter-vlan issue

Tags: cisco

I have two Cisco 3850 switches (3850-1, 3850-2). I have VLANs 1,2,3,4,5 setup (192.168.1.0 - 192.168.5.0) using built in DHCP from 3850-1.

3850-1 is 192.168.1.3
3850-2 is 192.168.1.4

I have an etherchannel setup between the two. I have them presently set to allow all VLANs (will limit later).

Each VLAN has HSRP configured so that a VIP stays active as the default gateway for each VLAN subnet.

I have a new Cisco 1852e WAP (MObility Express Mode). It's the Mobility Express Manager on 192.168.1.5.

if I connect a device (say an iPhone) to an SSID (Customer) that is setup for VLAN 3, it works great. The Device gets an IP address of 192.168.3.51, D/G 192.168.3.1. I can ping every IP but one (my 3850-1 switch, ip 192.168.1.3).

If I connect a device to SSID Employees, setup for VLAN 2, the device gets an IP address of 192.168.2.54 d/g 192.168.2.1. I can ping everything but 192.168.1.3 (3850-1).

THe crazy thing: 192.168.1.3 (3850-1) can ping the given IPs of either device, and so can 192.168.1.4 (3850-2). IF I SSH into either, they both can ping the devices on either SSID/Subnet/VLAN.

But neither device can ping 192.168.1.3 (3850-1).

I'm wondering if I have my Etherchannel setup wrong some how?

It's driving me nuts.  I'm not an expert at this. Let's just put this out there. I am so far unable to figure out why each switch can successfully ping any device on any SSID, but the devices cannot ping ONLY 192.168.1.3 (3850-1).

Here's my standby info from 3850-1:

```
3850-1#show standby br
                     P indicates configured to preempt.
                     |
Interface   Grp  Pri P State   Active          Standby         Virtual IP
Vl2         10   100 P Standby 192.168.2.3     local           192.168.2.1
Vl3         30   100 P Standby 192.168.3.3     local           192.168.3.1
Vl4         40   100 P Standby 192.168.4.3     local           192.168.4.1
```

and this is from 3850-2:

```
3850-2#sho standby br
                     P indicates configured to preempt.
                     |
Interface   Grp  Pri P State   Active          Standby         Virtual IP
Vl2         10   100 P Active  local           192.168.2.2     192.168.2.1
Vl3         30   100 P Active  local           192.168.3.2     192.168.3.1
Vl4         40   100 P Active  local           192.168.4.2     192.168.4.1
```

Here's my vlan trunking info from 3850-1:

```
3850-1#show int trunk

Port        Mode             Encapsulation  Status        Native vlan
Gi1/0/5     on               802.1q         trunking      1
Gi1/0/23    on               802.1q         trunking      1
Gi1/0/24    on               802.1q         trunking      1

Port        Vlans allowed on trunk
Gi1/0/5     1-4094
Gi1/0/23    1-4094
Gi1/0/24    1-4094

Port        Vlans allowed and active in management domain
Gi1/0/5     1-5,13
Gi1/0/23    1-5,13
Gi1/0/24    1-5,13

Port        Vlans in spanning tree forwarding state and not pruned
Gi1/0/5     1-5,13
Gi1/0/23    none
Gi1/0/24    1-5,13
```

and from 3850-2:

```
3850-2#show int trunk

Port        Mode             Encapsulation  Status        Native vlan
Gi1/0/11    on               802.1q         trunking      1
Gi1/0/23    on               802.1q         trunking      1
Gi1/0/24    on               802.1q         trunking      1

Port        Vlans allowed on trunk
Gi1/0/11    1-4094
Gi1/0/23    1-4094
Gi1/0/24    1-4094

Port        Vlans allowed and active in management domain
Gi1/0/11    1-5,13
Gi1/0/23    1-5,13
Gi1/0/24    1-5,13

Port        Vlans in spanning tree forwarding state and not pruned
Gi1/0/11    1-5,13
Gi1/0/23    1-5,13
Gi1/0/24    1
```

My 1852e is on 3850-2 G1/0/11. It is set up as a TRUNK port per Cisco's MObility express documentation to facilitate having SSIDs on various VLANs.

My ether channel is configured for g1/0/23 and g1/0/24 on each switch.

Here's my configs (3850-1):

```
!
! Last configuration change at 14:13:22 UTC Mon Jun 27 2016
!
version 15.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
service compress-config
!
hostname 3850-1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
vrf definition Mgmt-vrf
 !
 address-family ipv4
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family ipv6
 exit-address-family
!
logging console emergencies
enable secret 4 h0Ne.6akbVdjXZ6DzRvN1DHQNFi/WK0h2CApUGBYEF2
!
no aaa new-model
clock timezone UTC -5 0
clock summer-time UTC recurring
switch 1 provision ws-c3850-24t
!
!
!
!
!
ip routing
!
no ip dhcp conflict logging
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.50
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.2.1 192.168.2.50
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.3.1 192.168.3.50
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.4.1 192.168.4.50
!
ip dhcp pool 192.168.2.1
 network 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.2.1 
 dns-server 192.168.13.250 8.8.8.8 192.168.13.251 
 netbios-name-server 192.168.13.250 192.168.13.251 
 netbios-node-type h-node
!
ip dhcp pool 192.168.1.0
 network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
 dns-server 192.168.13.250 8.8.8.8 192.168.13.251 
 default-router 192.168.1.3 
 netbios-name-server 192.168.13.250 192.168.13.251 
 netbios-node-type h-node
!
ip dhcp pool 192.168.3.1
 network 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.3.1 
 dns-server 192.168.13.250 8.8.8.8 
 netbios-name-server 192.168.13.250 192.168.13.251 
 netbios-node-type h-node
!
ip dhcp pool 192.168.4.1
 network 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0
 dns-server 192.168.13.250 8.8.8.8 192.168.13.251 
 default-router 192.168.4.1 
 netbios-name-server 192.168.13.250 192.168.13.251 
 netbios-node-type h-node
!
!
qos wireless-default-untrust
qos queue-softmax-multiplier 100
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-1939811358
 enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-1939811358
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-1939811358
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-1939811358
 certificate self-signed 01
  3082023E 308201A7 A0030201 02020101 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 04050030 
  31312F30 2D060355 04031326 494F532D 53656C66 2D536967 6E65642D 43657274 
  69666963 6174652D 31393339 38313133 3538301E 170D3136 30353236 30383135 
  33355A17 0D323030 31303130 30303030 305A3031 312F302D 06035504 03132649 
  4F532D53 656C662D 5369676E 65642D43 65727469 66696361 74652D31 39333938 
  31313335 3830819F 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 01050003 818D0030 81890281 
  8100E6B8 E8FF2963 DEE3DD17 10EE39CB F2CB7271 9E9AD651 97446D51 BDE3D7A7 
  76B97FE8 C2E04D64 10123FE4 D407301C 30CFFFBC E813B22C 7F2C0253 FD2890C5 
  46BA859E 6950720F 585E3D02 1BE7E7EB 1E450758 1E496631 2FF61BCD BEC5035F 
  FEBCB503 88E5D05B 2A0262F7 CE0471CD AA8E3027 487730E0 F78BE317 BBFB4B67 
  4C130203 010001A3 66306430 0F060355 1D130101 FF040530 030101FF 30110603 
  551D1104 0A300882 06537769 74636830 1F060355 1D230418 30168014 A195FE1A 
  E1181495 C0D78655 DE8FA75D 8EBBA017 301D0603 551D0E04 160414A1 95FE1AE1 
  181495C0 D78655DE 8FA75D8E BBA01730 0D06092A 864886F7 0D010104 05000381 
  8100D556 C2170C0D FDD8DE80 40B96CBF 7D63D893 A6480140 D1A16E36 FB10A6A8 
  C626DCC6 62066503 002CD936 573C6A08 0F618DAF 5791F89A 0759E261 6E4E2E6F 
  062430D8 E6B7D922 1EADA08E 4BB3D45E E9744A8C 74F2CEBC AA442D6A EDEB7446 
  B05C4335 A8E40C8B E8175A36 6A11A057 9D8323BA 42F7214E C93A16F4 EED8C496 3D90
    quit
diagnostic bootup level minimal
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
hw-switch switch 1 logging onboard message level 3
!
redundancy
 mode sso
!
!
!
class-map match-any non-client-nrt-class
!
policy-map port_child_policy
 class non-client-nrt-class
  bandwidth remaining ratio 10
!
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Port-channel1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 vrf forwarding Mgmt-vrf
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 description Uplink to Firewall to TimeWarner
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
 description was to fiber transceiver in room west of W1
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
 description long haul to box room (west) into 5 port switch
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/9
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/10
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11
 switchport access vlan 3
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/13
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/14
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/15
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/16
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/17
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/18
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/19
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/21
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/23
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/24
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/4
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/4
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.1.3 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 192.168.1.3
!
interface Vlan2
 ip address 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 192.168.2.1
 standby 10 ip 192.168.2.1
 standby 10 timers msec 200 msec 750
 standby 10 preempt delay minimum 300
!
interface Vlan3
 ip address 192.168.3.2 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 192.168.3.1
 standby 30 ip 192.168.3.1
 standby 30 timers msec 200 msec 750
 standby 30 preempt delay minimum 300
!
interface Vlan4
 ip address 192.168.4.2 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 192.168.4.1
 standby 40 ip 192.168.4.1
 standby 40 timers msec 200 msec 750
 standby 40 preempt delay minimum 300
!
interface Vlan5
 ip address 192.168.5.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan13
 ip address 192.168.13.1 255.255.255.0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 Vlan1
ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 Vlan2
ip route 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0 Vlan3
ip route 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0 Vlan4
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 password 275woodward
 login
line vty 5 15
 password 275woodward
 login
!
wsma agent exec
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
wsma agent config
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
wsma agent filesys
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
wsma agent notify
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
!
wsma profile listener httplistener
 transport http
!
wsma profile listener httpslistener
 transport https
!
ap group default-group
end
```

And finally, here is the config from 3850-2:

```
!
! Last configuration change at 14:13:22 UTC Mon Jun 27 2016
!
version 15.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
service compress-config
!
hostname 3850-1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
vrf definition Mgmt-vrf
 !
 address-family ipv4
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family ipv6
 exit-address-family
!
logging console emergencies
enable secret 4 h0Ne.6akbVdjXZ6DzRvN1DHQNFi/WK0h2CApUGBYEF2
!
no aaa new-model
clock timezone UTC -5 0
clock summer-time UTC recurring
switch 1 provision ws-c3850-24t
!
!
!
!
!
ip routing
!
no ip dhcp conflict logging
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.50
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.2.1 192.168.2.50
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.3.1 192.168.3.50
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.4.1 192.168.4.50
!
ip dhcp pool 192.168.2.1
 network 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.2.1 
 dns-server 192.168.13.250 8.8.8.8 192.168.13.251 
 netbios-name-server 192.168.13.250 192.168.13.251 
 netbios-node-type h-node
!
ip dhcp pool 192.168.1.0
 network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
 dns-server 192.168.13.250 8.8.8.8 192.168.13.251 
 default-router 192.168.1.3 
 netbios-name-server 192.168.13.250 192.168.13.251 
 netbios-node-type h-node
!
ip dhcp pool 192.168.3.1
 network 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.3.1 
 dns-server 192.168.13.250 8.8.8.8 
 netbios-name-server 192.168.13.250 192.168.13.251 
 netbios-node-type h-node
!
ip dhcp pool 192.168.4.1
 network 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0
 dns-server 192.168.13.250 8.8.8.8 192.168.13.251 
 default-router 192.168.4.1 
 netbios-name-server 192.168.13.250 192.168.13.251 
 netbios-node-type h-node
!
!
qos wireless-default-untrust
qos queue-softmax-multiplier 100
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-1939811358
 enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-1939811358
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-1939811358
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-1939811358
 certificate self-signed 01
  3082023E 308201A7 A0030201 02020101 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 04050030 
  31312F30 2D060355 04031326 494F532D 53656C66 2D536967 6E65642D 43657274 
  69666963 6174652D 31393339 38313133 3538301E 170D3136 30353236 30383135 
  33355A17 0D323030 31303130 30303030 305A3031 312F302D 06035504 03132649 
  4F532D53 656C662D 5369676E 65642D43 65727469 66696361 74652D31 39333938 
  31313335 3830819F 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 01050003 818D0030 81890281 
  8100E6B8 E8FF2963 DEE3DD17 10EE39CB F2CB7271 9E9AD651 97446D51 BDE3D7A7 
  76B97FE8 C2E04D64 10123FE4 D407301C 30CFFFBC E813B22C 7F2C0253 FD2890C5 
  46BA859E 6950720F 585E3D02 1BE7E7EB 1E450758 1E496631 2FF61BCD BEC5035F 
  FEBCB503 88E5D05B 2A0262F7 CE0471CD AA8E3027 487730E0 F78BE317 BBFB4B67 
  4C130203 010001A3 66306430 0F060355 1D130101 FF040530 030101FF 30110603 
  551D1104 0A300882 06537769 74636830 1F060355 1D230418 30168014 A195FE1A 
  E1181495 C0D78655 DE8FA75D 8EBBA017 301D0603 551D0E04 160414A1 95FE1AE1 
  181495C0 D78655DE 8FA75D8E BBA01730 0D06092A 864886F7 0D010104 05000381 
  8100D556 C2170C0D FDD8DE80 40B96CBF 7D63D893 A6480140 D1A16E36 FB10A6A8 
  C626DCC6 62066503 002CD936 573C6A08 0F618DAF 5791F89A 0759E261 6E4E2E6F 
  062430D8 E6B7D922 1EADA08E 4BB3D45E E9744A8C 74F2CEBC AA442D6A EDEB7446 
  B05C4335 A8E40C8B E8175A36 6A11A057 9D8323BA 42F7214E C93A16F4 EED8C496 3D90
    quit
diagnostic bootup level minimal
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
hw-switch switch 1 logging onboard message level 3
!
redundancy
 mode sso
!
!
!
class-map match-any non-client-nrt-class
!
policy-map port_child_policy
 class non-client-nrt-class
  bandwidth remaining ratio 10
!
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Port-channel1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 vrf forwarding Mgmt-vrf
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 description Uplink to Firewall to TimeWarner
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
 description was to fiber transceiver in room west of W1
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
 description long haul to box room (west) into 5 port switch
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/9
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/10
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11
 switchport access vlan 3
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/13
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/14
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/15
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/16
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/17
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/18
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/19
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/21
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/23
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/24
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/4
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/4
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.1.3 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 192.168.1.3
!
interface Vlan2
 ip address 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 192.168.2.1
 standby 10 ip 192.168.2.1
 standby 10 timers msec 200 msec 750
 standby 10 preempt delay minimum 300
!
interface Vlan3
 ip address 192.168.3.2 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 192.168.3.1
 standby 30 ip 192.168.3.1
 standby 30 timers msec 200 msec 750
 standby 30 preempt delay minimum 300
!
interface Vlan4
 ip address 192.168.4.2 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 192.168.4.1
 standby 40 ip 192.168.4.1
 standby 40 timers msec 200 msec 750
 standby 40 preempt delay minimum 300
!
interface Vlan5
 ip address 192.168.5.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan13
 ip address 192.168.13.1 255.255.255.0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 Vlan1
ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 Vlan2
ip route 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0 Vlan3
ip route 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0 Vlan4
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 password 275woodward
 login
line vty 5 15
 password 275woodward
 login
!
wsma agent exec
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
wsma agent config
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
wsma agent filesys
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
wsma agent notify
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
!
wsma profile listener httplistener
 transport http
!
wsma profile listener httpslistener
 transport https
!
ap group default-group
end
```

Comment: PS. Devices on 192.168.1.0 (outside the two switches) cannot ping a device on either 192.168.3.x or 192.168.2.x. But each switch can ping any device on any vlan/subnet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Etherchannel wasn't setup completely. Switched to LACP from PAgP. THis link helped.

Essentially, I had an incomplete configuration on one end. Going through and rebuilding int PO1 on each switch using LACP instead of PAgP fixed it. Works great.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-LACP-and-PAGP-protocol

Comment: You can skip the channel negotiation and just use `channel-group 1 mode on`. This will force the switches to channel unconditionally.